# Get the same field from different structures using the same function in C

Tags: c, types, ansi-c

I want to have two structures in C, for example:

A:

```
typedef struct a
{
     char *text;
     int something;
}A;
```

and B:

```
typedef struct b
{
     char *text;
     float something_else;
}B;
```

Now, as far as I know, it is not possible to have a function which takes a `void *` parameter to get the `text` element from both structures. Am I wrong, is this possible in standard C?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What are you trying to do?  [Explain what problem you're trying to solve, instead of telling us the mechanism you're using to try and solve it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  Alternatively, provide a more detailed example, including the function you're trying to use to extract the text element using a void * parameter.  Offhand, I'd say you need a `union`, but that might be bad advice if I can't fully comprehend your problem.

Comment: Ok, so as I said I have two structures, one of the type A and of the type B. Now I want to pass both to a function:
`void func(void *data)` and now I want to get the text entry of both structures. is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, using casting and the fact that the `text` element is the first element of both structures:

```
void f(void *t)
{
    printf("%s\n", *((char **)t));
}

int main()
{
     struct a AA = {"hello",3};
     struct b BB = {"world",4.0};

     f(&AA);
     f(&BB);
     return 0;
 }
```

Note: Passing the address of the struct means it points to the address of `text`. This must then still be dereferenced one more time to get at the adress of the text itself, which is then passed to printf.

Edit: a cast to `(void *)` in the calls to `f` are not necessary (casts removed).

Comment: This looks good, but is this also possible if I have multiple `char*` elements and or it is not the first element?

Comment: If it is not the first element(s), then this will not work. Take a look at unions.